# Write variable in quotes to output file

Tags: batch-file

```
(for %%f in (%zipfiles%) do (
  <nul set /p ="%%f",
  certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256|find /v ":" || echo empty file
))> "C:\Location\Report\ListOfFiles.csv"
```

the "%%f" does not work, neither %%"f" nor "/p =%%f",

What I want is the filename in quotes:

```
"Filename 001.zip",68b17a9d0d98dd64f3c6c5b29e5cd304a6397d21f24e3087723ccad9f6f77c58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "zipfiles=*.zip"
(for %%f in (%zipfiles%) do (
  <nul set /p =""%%f","
  certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256|find /v ":" || echo empty file
))>".\ListOfFiles.csv"
```

Here in `<nul set /p =""%%f","`:

- outer double quotes used to [escape the comma](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) as well as inner double quotes so that
- inner double quotes and the comma are copied to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "zipfiles=file*"
(for %%f in (%zipfiles%) do (
 if %%~zf==0 (echo "%%~ff",empty file
 ) else for /f "delims=" %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256^|find /v ":"') do echo "%%~ff",%%a
))> "u:\ListOfFiles.csv"

GOTO :EOF
```

Simple enough - no tricks. I tried with files named `filename*` on my machine. Simply use `%%~zf` for zero-length files to produce *that* name and otherwise select only the non-`:`-containing lines for `certutil` output to build the other lines; `^` used to escape the pipe so the `certutil` output is filtered.

destination filename also changed to suit my system.